# Does SQL Server round or truncate?

Tags: sql-server, math, floating-point

Say I'm inserting a 64 bit floating point double into a DECIMAL(17,5) field. Does the value get rounded or truncated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It rounds:

```
select cast(9.12345 as decimal(10,4))
```

Returns `9.1235`

Comment: Good test. You could also create a temp table to test it out.

Comment: @Esteban: I suppose you could, but I'm lazy.